# MVC obtaining active directory user name

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do you obtain the username of the logged in user with MVC2 in ASP.NET web forms I used to do it with:

User.Identity.Name

This works when I am testing on my local machine using visual studio but no longer works once the project is published to the test server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a setting on the Virtual Directory. The option "enable anonymous access" was selected. Once this was de-selected everything worked as expected.